# Minimum amount of execution time before proceeding

Tags: node.js, for-loop, timer, stack

So I need to make my for loop wait AT LEAST 124ms before executing the next loop run, note that it can however take more than 124ms to complete the stuff inside the loop as I'm getting data from a website's API and that has to be received before moving on.

My idea was someting like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var startTime = Date.now();
    //Do some stuff

    executeTimeCheck();
    function executeTimeCheck()
    {
        setTimeout(executeTimeCheck, 1);
        if(((Date.now()) - startTime) >= 124){return;}
        else{executeTimeCheck(); return;}
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep running out of stack *(RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded)*. If you have any idea how to make this work please let me know.

Comment: `function executeTimeCheck()    {   setTimeout(executeTimeCheck, 1)`  this leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: Even if I just call it without timeout I still get the same thing. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, you create an infinite loop. In your code you just do `function x() { x(); }`, So whenever the function is called you call it again, with no stopping condition. To stop this from happening you need to exit the function (return) **before** calling it again.

Comment: Well I lack the knowledge to make this timer loop work with the way you described.

Comment: IMHO, you should be using promises for all this, and not mess around with timing.